# firebase firestore: Performing SQL-like joins

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase but I have a `users` collection in which each user document will have the following fields

- `username`
- `avatar` (the profile picture)
- `name`

Each user can post a comment which will be stored inside a `comments` collection with these fields

- `createdAt`
- `username` (the user who commented)
- `userAvatar` (the user's avatar)

when it comes to retrieving the comments I can display every single comment with the user who commented (`username`) and the `userAvatar`. The problem though each comment has static `username` and `userAvatar` fields and if I were to change the user's avatar inside a user document, I'd like to modify the userAvatar inside the related comment document too for more data consistency.
To achieve this I thought about creating a cloud function trigger to listen to the user's `avatar` update for changing the comment `userAvatar` accordingly. but I quickly realized it was a bad move in terms of cost since the cloud function would be triggered each and every time a change occurs inside the user's document regardless of if it is an `avatar` change or not.

So I decided to create a user reference inside the comment document since it works like referenced keys in SQL databases like this

- `createdAt`
- `user: db.doc('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`

Now the main issue is that if I wanted to retrieve let say 15 comments from the database, for each and every comment we will also have to get the user informations. so we'll have something like this

```
exports.getComments = async (req, res) => {
try {
  let comments = [];
  const data = await db
   .collection("comments")
   .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
   .get();
  data.forEach((doc) => {
    let comment = doc.data();
    doc.data().user
     .get()
     .then(element => {
        comment.avatar = element.data().avatar;
        comment.username = element.data().username;
        comments.push(comment);
     })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  });
 return res.json(comments);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json({ e });
}
};
```

now I'm wondering what if I had 1000 comments? in terms of latency, the app will not provide a good user experience. isn't it possible to retrieve data from both user and comment collection at once?

Comment: Question: If I'm Robert today, I post a comment, and change my name to Freddie tomorrow - who posted the comment? Robert or Freddie?

Comment: @RobertKawecki you can change your name to. since the comment only takes the user reference if you change your user informatiions the comment will change as well. But i'll make it difficult to change the username. username will be an additional identifier to email or document id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind two things about Firestore:

- query execution time depends on the size *of the result set*, and not on the total number of documents
- we cannot do join queries (this is a consequence of the constraint on execution time) *

a few solutions come to mind to handle your comments and users:

## Data modeling

### Duplicate the user info in the comments

This was your first approach and it is the suggested way for dealing with such cases in NoSQL, it is coined "de-normalization". As you pointed out, it means that when a user's name or avatar changes, you have to modify all associated comments with a Cloud Function.
However, as pointed out by @RobertKawecki (or is it Freddie? ), you should probably keep the initial name and avatar as it was the correct thing *at the point of comment creation*.
More details on this technique can be viewed in this [Firebase presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW7DWV2jST0).

### Store comments in user documents

You could reverse the problem and store comments in a subcollection in user documents. Then you can use [collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) queries to retrieve all comments. Personally I might go this way ;)

## Latency optimization

Now if you still don't want to duplicate the user data in the comments, performance can be improved over your initial code in a few ways.

The current latency of your function is 15 + 15 unit of time as you fetch 15 documents from the comments collection (I think you forgot the limit clause in your code), then 15 documents from the users collection (I think you forgot to add [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in your code).

### Use caching

Ok this one is basic and will bring little improvement. Suppose that in your 15 last comments, some belong to the same user. If you cache users while you retrieve them, you can spare querying multiple times for the same user. The latency will be reduced to **15 + (15 - number of duplicated users)**.

### ⛷️ Parallelize

In your function you fetch comments first, then fetch the needed user documents. You could parallelize the fetch using the [stream API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#stream): stream your comments, as soon as you receive one, fetch the associated user document in parallel. The code is a little too involved to type it here. This would bring the latency to **15 + 1**

### ☎️ Fetch the data from the front-end

This one can be a great latency saver. You can use Firestore [front-end SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) for web or mobile to query your database directly from the front-end. There you can use a [snapshot listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) on the comments collection, and fetch the associated user on each reveived comment (like in the parallelize solution), and display it right away.
This brings the latency to **2** . Hard to beat! And you also get offline support!

* As a side note, you can perform a join query if you maintain a join table, but it won't help you in your case as it requires another collection and Cloud Functions, and it wouldn't reduce latency. I wrote an article about it [here](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-secure-many-to-many-relationships-in-firestore-d19f972fd4d3).

Comment: @LoouisCoulet thank you so much for your answer it was super clear and concise. I initially designed my app with express APIs to perform queries on the backend cause i thought it would the app much lighter but I think I will tweak it to query directly from the front end. Now, what data modeling should i pick for such kind of situation (de-normalization) or the one with "Sub-collection"?.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Querying from the front-end is the best choice IMO. This way you don't have a latency problem anymore, so you don't need to de-normalize either way (user info into each comment doc, or comments in a sub-collection in each user doc). You can keep users and comments separated without duplicating any data.